# How to get the chest in beginning of Ikana Canyon in Majora's Mask?

Tags: zelda-majoras-mask

When just entering Ikana Canyon from Termina Field there is a red spot on the ground and the minimap shows a chest there. I have tried several methods in getting the chest but nothing has worked thus far:

- Bomb
- Bombchu
- Powder Keg
- Flipping the nearby real bombchu
- Song of Storms
- Song of Healing
- Gibdo Mask, Garo's Mask, Captain's Hat, and other masks
- Goron Mask with a pound move
- Elegy of Emptiness to create multiple statues on top
- Fire, Ice, and Light Arrows
- Eye of Truth doesn't reveal anything

The spot of interest can be seen in this picture:
[image: Red Spot in Ikana Canyon]

Comment: this might be a dumb question but have you looked up? Maybe theres a ledge above you (or an invisible one) that has the chest on it? Been a looooong time since I played through this game.. kind of makes me want to again.

Comment: Yes, looked up with Lens of Truth. My most recent attempt has been trying to use that nearby ramp with the Goron speed rolling but there isn't enough space to get up to full speed.

Comment: Have you come back on the second and third day?

Comment: According to this somewhat official looking map, there's only 20 rupees in it: http://www.zeldacentral.com/images/mm/ikana.jpg

Comment: @KyleRone turned out it was above me on top of the leaning pillar to the left, in plain view, just need hookshot. I can't believe I couldn't find it!

Comment: @ZekeHernandez - that map helped! Realized the chest was no on the red patch but across on the other side of the valley.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's right behind you on top of a pillar:

[image]